# Rasa Bot button click not response

Tags: python, rasa-nlu, rasa, rasa-core

I try to learn rasa chatbot , i try to button click and relavent intent comes in. But when i clicked button in template waitin symbol comes after that gone which i was choosen and not response come. If try to write "muhtesem" bot understand and response me. How can i fix this button problem? thanks
[image: after this moment my choosen gone]

```
class ActionCarousel(Action):
def name(self) -> Text:
    return "action_carousels"

def run(self, dispatcher, tracker: Tracker, domain: "DomainDict") -> List[Dict[Text, Any]]:
    message = {
        "type": "template",
        "payload": {
            "template_type": "generic",
            "elements": [
                {
                    "title": "Merhaba, bugün nasılsın?",
                    "subtitle": "$10",
                    "image_url": "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSqhmyBRCngkU_OKSL6gBQxCSH-cufgmZwb2w&usqp=CAU",
                    "buttons": [ 
                        {
                        "title": "Muhteşem",
                        "payload": "happy",
                        "type": "postback"
                        },
                        {
                        "title": "Üzgün",
                        "payload": "sad",
                        "type": "postback"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "title": "Carousel 2",
                    "subtitle": "$12",
                    "image_url": "https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/city-illustration_23-2147514701.jpg",
                    "buttons": [ 
                        {
                        "title": "Click here",
                        "url": "https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/city-illustration_23-2147514701.jpg",
                        "type": "web_url"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
            }
    }
    dispatcher.utter_message(attachment=message)
    return []
```

This is template code.  Thank for supports.

Answer (score 1):

The payload for the button "Muhteşem" is "happy", not "Muhteşem". This means that it should the equivalent of typing "happy" to the bot.

For questions like this you are better asking on the rasa forum: https://forum.rasa.com/

Comment: thanks i changed "payload":"muhteşem" and its done.